# OneToMany Relation on cross project entities (Symfony2/Doctrine)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Anybody knows how to accomplish a `OneToMany` relation within 2 projects (let's say cross-database wise, both have their own project structure, namespaces and database).

Let's say I have one Entity in Project A:

**Movie.php (Entity Project A)**

```php
class Movie {

    // ... some other properties

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Moviechild/Project B", mappedBy="movie")
     */
    protected $moviechilds;

    // ...
```

and another Entity in Project B:

**Moviechild.php (Entity Project B)**

```php
class Moviechild {

    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Movie/Project A", inversedBy="moviechilds")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movie_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $movie;

    // ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instantiate `ProjectBBundle` inside Project A's `AppKernel` and vice versa.

Then **use correct namespaces** inside `targetEntity` property annotation:

**Movie.php (Entity Project A)**

```php
namespace ProjectABundle\Entity;

class Movie {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjectBBundle\Entity\Moviechild", mappedBy="movie")
     */
    protected $moviechilds;

    // ...
```

**Moviechild.php (Entity Project B)**

```php
namespace ProjectBBundle\Entity;

class Moviechild {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProjectABundle\Entity\Movie", inversedBy="moviechilds")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movie_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $movie;

    // ...
```

Comment: Yes thanks Florent, actually I had to do it differently, because the project was changing. But thanks for your answer, I appreciate it very much! Best