# Programmatically modify table's schema name in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to modify a table's schema/DB name at runtime [as is possible with the table name](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/sql-table-prefixes.html), but the `ClassMetadataInfo` class does not appear to expose an interface to get/set this property.

I can make do with modifying table names at runtime if absolutely necessary, but it is not an ideal solution due to the amount of tables we would then have to store in a single schema/DB.

Is there a way to achieve what I'd like to do? Thanks in advance.

Note: I need to be able to provide a fully qualified table name using a schema placeholder in my annotation-based entity mapping (like `__schema_placeholder__.table_name`, for cross-database joins). At runtime I would then like to dynamically remap the entity from  `__schema_placeholder__.table_name` => `real_schema_name.table_name`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can dynamically adjust the table names ( and mappings ) by hooking into the [doctrine event-system](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#load-classmetadata-event) with listeners/subscribers.

i.e. "loadClassMetadata" is one of [doctrine's events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) you can create a listener/subscriber for as described in the cookbook article [How to Register Event Listeners and Subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html).

### Example

<kbd>config.yml</kbd>

```
services:
    mapping.listener:
        class: Acme\YourBundle\EventListener\MappingListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: loadClassMetadata }
```

<kbd>MappingListener</kbd>

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

class MappingListener
{
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();
        $table = $classMetadata->table;

        $oldName = $table['name'];      // ... or $classMetaData->getTableName()

        // your logic here ...

        $table['name'] = 'new_table_name';

        $classMetadata->setPrimaryTable($table);

        // ... or add a field-mapping like this

        $fieldMapping = array(
          'fieldName' => 'about',
          'type' => 'string',
           'length' => 255
        );
        $classMetadata->mapField($fieldMapping);
```

[ClassMetadata](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php) extends [ClassMetadataInfo](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php) and provides a public variable "[table](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L431)" ( containing the mapping information provided by your annotations or yml ) which you can modify !

The public table variable is an array with the following entries:

- name =>
- schema =>
- indexes => array
- uniqueConstraints => array

You can dynamically register event-listeners/subscribers in your controller prior to saving/updating.

```
$mappingListener = new MappingListener();

// ... maybe even modify the listener using reflection

$evm = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager()->->getEventManager();
$evm->addEventListener('loadClassMetadata', $mappingListener);
```

---

Furthermore you can introduce multiple database connections/names and access them in your application.

**app/config/config.yml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            customer:
                driver:   "%database_driver2%"
                host:     "%database_host2%"
                port:     "%database_port2%"
                dbname:   "%database_name2%"
                user:     "%database_user2%"
                password: "%database_password2%"
                charset:  UTF8
```

Then get different entity managers using ...

```
  $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('default');
  $em2 = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('customer');
```

or repositories

```
$customers = $this->get('doctrine')
    ->getRepository('AcmeCustomerBundle:Customer', 'customer')
    ->findAll()
;
```

... or [add connections](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/connections.html) dynamically

```
$this->get('doctrine')
  ->connection('mysql://username:password@localhost/test', 'dynamic_connection');
```

Read more about the topic in the cookbook chapter [How to work with Multiple Entity Managers and Connections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve my particular problem as I will also need to do cross-database joins, and therefore have to provide the fully qualified table name (schema.table) in the Doctrine ORM mapping. I could likely do this with a parameter in a YAML mapping configuration, but I'm using annotations and do not wish to convert.

I need to be able to map an entity to `__schema_placeholder__.tableName` and then dynamically change the mapping by replacing this schema placeholder with the actual name.

Comment: i have exended my answer with new information which should help you resolve the issue. Please show some credit by at least upvoting ... maybe accepting or commenting if you need further information.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. That's what I get for reading the Events chapter at 3 AM. Upvoted and accepted, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the undocumented 'options' parameter in @Table and pass a variable to the listener which you can use to decide which database to use.

'options' is used to include DBMS specific options in the SQL when generating the schema. For example: "charset"="utf8mb4", "engine"="InnoDB", etc

When choosing a variable name, make sure it is not a valid option supported by your DBMS. In the below example I have chosen 'schema':

```
@ORM\Table(name="person", options={"schema"="readonly"})
```

After that I have created a parameter array in services.yml called 'schema', which will be passed to the service via the ParameterBag. The values are either edited in the yml, or pulled from the environmental variables.

```
parameters:
    env(SCHEMA_READONLY): 'readonly_database' #default if env variable has not been set
    schema:
        readonly: 'readonly_database'
        client: 'client_database'
        runtime: '%env(SCHEMA_READONLY)%' #pulled from env variables
```

Now my listener looks like this:

```
class MappingListener
{
    protected $parameterBag;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag) {
        $this->parameterBag = $parameterBag;
    }

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs) {
        $schemaParamaters = $this->parameterBag->has('schema') ? $this->parameterBag->get('schema') : array();

        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

        if(isset($classMetadata->table['options']['schema']) && isset($schemaParamaters[$classMetadata->table['options']['schema']])) {
            $classMetadata->setPrimaryTable(['schema' => $schemaParamaters[$classMetadata->table['options']['schema']]]);
        }
    } 
}
```

This results in all entities with the table option 'schema' will be set to use the database that is defined in the parameters in the service.yml or in environmental variables.

This means you can choose to set the schema, or leave it as default, without editing the entities or any other class.