# Dynamic Table/Entity names in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine

I am hoping someone can shed some light on what is going on with my code.

I need to have an entity that represents a generic table as a model for tables with X id suffix.  For example, I have an entity: CustomerX
The tables I need to query are cusotmer_1, customer_2, customer_3...etc..

I am currently using:

```
class CustomerX {
/**
 * CustomerX
 *
 * @Table(name="customer_")
 * @Entity
 */


//..... properties and setters/getters....

private $_tableName = null;

public function getTableName() {
    return $this->_tableName;
}

public function setTableName($tableName) {
    $this->_tableName = $tableName;
    return $this;
}

public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

    $table = $classMetadata->table;
    $table['name'] = 'customer_'.$this->getTableName();
    $classMetadata->setPrimaryTable($table);
}


public static function getCustomerRecords($CustomerId) {
    $em = \Helper_Doctrine::em();

    $custTable = new \ME\CustomerX();
    $custTable->setTableName($CustomerId);
    $evm = $em->getEventManager();
    $evm->addEventListener(\Doctrine\ORM\Events::loadClassMetadata, $custTable);

    //get the customer info
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT w
         FROM \ME\CustomerX w
         WHERE w.customerId = :CustId';
    $query->setParameter('CustId', $CustomerId);
    $custParams = $query->getResult();

    $evm->removeEventListener(\Doctrine\ORM\Events::loadClassMetadata, $custTable);
    $em->flush();

    return $custParams;
}

}
```

So the issue is, i can get this to set correctly the first time I run through getting a customer, but then the second time, the sql generated by doctrine ends up using the first table I created.

So if i run: CustomerX::getCustomerRecords('123') first, the sql that gets executed and when I run CustomerX::getCustomerRecords('987') still is using 'customer_123'.

I must be doing something wrong. If anyone has any suggestions on how to correctly remove or reset the table name to something new, that would be great.

Thanks.

I initially used this as reference.
[Programmatically modify table's schema name in Doctrine2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134855/programmatically-modify-tables-schema-name-in-doctrine2)

Comment: **Update**:

I can get this to work if I $em->close(); and the end of the ::getCustomerRecords() method.

The issue is that this obviously doesnt seem right and from my understanding, clear should do this, but it's not.

Hoping I am on the right track at this point.

Comment: Is the loadClassMetadata function called each time your entity is call ? or do you define something like listener ?

Answer (score 6):

Question is old, but it can be helpful for someone.

If loadClassMetada called each time then it seems that issue in your code.
But, I suppose, that metadata is cached by doctrine.
In that case you can change it directly, please look following code snippet, it should work:

```
<?php
class FooController extends Controller {
  function fooAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $cm = $em->getClassMetadata('FooBundle:FooEntity');
    $cm->setTableName('special_table_name');
    $repo = $em->getRepository('FooBundle:FooEntity');
    $entities = $repo->createQueryBuilder('f')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->orderBy('f.id', 'desc')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    return new Response('');
  }
}
```

Comment: More modern way of doing this looks like `$cm->setPrimaryTable(['name' => 'special_table_name']);`. Be aware of doing it in Controller because of possible problems in the future. It's better to create and use some ConfigurationService and implement it in it's constructor just to avoid code duplication and to have initialization in one place.