# doctrine create an entity dynamically

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

Is there a way to create and *modify* entities and tables in a db dynamically (from a php script)?

For example, I want to generate an entity from an array:

```
fields{
    id: integer,
    name: string,
    ... and so on
}
```

And than generate a table in the bd

I know only one simple solution: to create yml or xml file and run a console command from my script, or use DBAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know only one simple solution: to create yml or xml file and run a console command from my script, or use DBAL

You can also [generate an entity from command line](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html), for example:

```
$ php app/console generate:doctrine:entity --no-interaction \
    --entity=AcmeBlogBundle:Post \
    --fields="id:integer title:string(100) body:text" \
    --format=xml
```

This uses the SensioGeneratorBundle, that is [defined only in `dev` and `test` environments](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/f5b1ae88c3d2338f43a18363811f03bae196ff54/app/AppKernel.php#L25).

So, it is a little bit hacky but you'll need to call this command with the right environment:

```
$ php app/console generate:doctrine:entity […] --env=dev
```

The [Process component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) can be used in order to launch this command.

So you may end up with something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

$command = 'php app/console generate:doctrine:entity --no-interaction '.
    '--entity=AcmeBlogBundle:Post '.
    '--fields="id:integer title:string(100) body:text" '.
    '--format=xml';

$process = new Process($command);
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

Comment: so this would be the solution for production systems as well? and the "--format=xml" part generates an xml file that represents the entity?

Comment: I would not recommend this for a production system, unless it's heavily tested. I used XML format because it was cited in the question. You can use other formats too.