# Symfony/Doctrine: Entity "schema" annotation not environment dependent?

Tags: annotations, doctrine, symfony, functional-testing

I am having trouble with getting functional tests to run in Symfony3 with Doctrine.
I have the code organized in two bundles with which need to be accessed by one EntityManager with entities stored in two different MySQL databases.
To achieve this, all Entities have a "schema" annotation in their definition, like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM/Table(name="tablename", schema="schema")
 * @Entity( ... )
 */
```

Without this setting, it has been my experience, that the Doctrine schema:create tool is not able to correctly create the entities in the right databases.
However it appears, that the schema annotation is not considered to be environment dependent.

So when I want to run functional tests that need to load fixtures, the ORMPurger tries to purge schema.tablename, where it should use the table/schema "test_schema".

Is there any way to keep the schema annotation but make it dependent on the environment, so that when the environment is "test", a different schema is used?

**EDIT:**

It appears that using the "schema" annotation for entities is pretty terrible all around when you are using different Symfony environments. At least when used in conjunction with MySQl, at least I think that that is the reason, since MySQL doesn't actually support schemas.
Every Symfony or Doctrine command I tried to take the schema annotation literally, regardless of the --env setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some more digging and found what I needed to do perfectly laid out here:

[Programmatically modify table's schema name in Doctrine2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134855/programmatically-modify-tables-schema-name-in-doctrine2)

So I added an EventListener, that adds the correct schema according to the EM used so I don't need hard-coded schema annotations anymore.

Heres the code for the Listener I've made:

```
<?php

namespace /* ... */

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

class MappingListener
{
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        /** @var EntityManagerInterface $entityManager */
        $entityManager = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        /** @var ClassMetadata $classMetadata */
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

        $database = $entityManager->getConnection()->getDatabase();

        $classMetadata->table['schema'] = $database;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Works, but the correct way to edit the schema is by using: `$classMetadata->setPrimaryTable(['schema' => $database]);` as the table property is documented as read-only.