# Unable to load an entity that is not related to a bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am building a company Symfony2 library that includes several bundles and a library of classes that can be used by any code. The plan is to eventually turn this into an internal package and install it into projects via composer so that it will live in the vendor directory.

One component of the library has a pair of database entity classes and a single repository class associated with it.

Because the only logic associated with these classes is contained in the repository class, it doesn't seem to make sense to to surround it with a bundle.

I have, as yet, been unable to get Doctrine to load this repository. It initially failed with a

> The class 'Dplh\Library\DplhEnum\Entity\EnumGroupRepository' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Dplh\DplhSecurityBundle\Entity

exception. (The reference to my security bundle was initially rather confusing. Turns out that this is Doctrine helping out by listing all of the known entity namespaces (see [Symfony error The class XXX was not found in the chain configured namespaces XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813300/symfony-error-the-class-xxx-was-not-found-in-the-chain-configured-namespaces-xxx))).

As I understand it, this happens because Doctrine is configured to use auto-mapping and expects all entities to be defined in src/WhateverBundle/Entity directories.

This can be changed with additional Doctrine configuration for specific mappings in config.yml (http://zalas.eu/how-to-store-doctrine-entities-outside-of-a-symfony-bundle/).

So far, I have been unable to get this to work either. I expect it's a minor config thing somewhere. I added the following to config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      # ...
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

        mappings:
            DplhEnum:
                type:       annotation
                is_bundle:  false
                dir:        %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Dplh/Library/DplhEnum/Entity
                prefix:     Dplh\Library\DplhEnum\Entity
                alias:      DplhEnum
```

I get two different exceptions depending on my call to getRepository().

```
// Using the fully-qualified class name.
$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Dplh\Library\DplhEnum\Entity\EnumGroup' )
```

This throws

> Attempted to load class "EnumGroupRepository" from namespace "Dplh\DplhEnumBundle\Entity".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

```
// Using the alias.
$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('DplhEnum\EnumGroup' )
```

this throws

> Class 'DplhEnum\EnumGroup' does not exist

I have verified that the *EnumGroupRepository.php* file is in the *src/Dplh/Library/DplhEnum/Entity* directory and the *EnumGroupRepository* class is in the *Dplh\Library\DplhEnum\Entity* namespace and that they are in the correct directory.

Comment: I think you need to use a colon for namespaces getRepository('DplhEnum:EnumGroup')

Comment: Well. That's interesting. Using 'DplhEnum:DplhEnum' throws "Attempted to load class "EnumGroupRepository" from namespace "Dplh\DplhEnumBundle\Entity".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?". Note the DplhEnumBundle reference. Odd.

Comment: Using `getRepository('DplhEnum:EnumGroup')` should work. Is your entity defined under the `Dplh\Library\DplhEnum\Entity` namespace?

Comment: Yes, it is. And it's in the src/Dplh/Library/DplhEnum/Entity directory.