# Symfony2 genj/faq-bundle

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I'm trying to install the **genj/faq-bundle** on Symfony 2.8. I have followed the step in the documentation: https://github.com/genj/GenjFaqBundle

But when I'm trying to do the schema update. There is nothing to update.
And when I go to the `/faq` route, I have this error:

`The class 'Genj\FaqBundle\Entity\Category' was not found in the chain configured namespaces FM\UserBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Entity`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it... It was a **mapping** problem in my **config.yml**. The `auto_mapping` was false

```
auto_mapping: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the force flag?

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: yes I did. Do I have create a class which extend this bundle?

Comment: [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813300/symfony-error-the-class-xxx-was-not-found-in-the-chain-configured-namespaces-xxx)