# The class 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Cursor' was not found in the chain configured namespaces AppBundle\Document

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, odm

In a repository I have this code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository;

class ItemRepository extends DocumentRepository
{
    public function findAllQueryBuilder($filter = '')
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('item');

        if ($filter) {
            $cat = $this->getDocumentManager()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')
                ->findAllQueryBuilder($filter)->getQuery()->execute();


            $qb->field('category')->includesReferenceTo($cat);
        }

        return $qb;
    }
}
```

But it throw this error:

```
The class 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Cursor' was not found in the chain configured namespaces AppBundle\Document
```

What is the problem?

I checked the `$cat`, it returns correct `category` document.

Comment: could you add where you defined your entity and the ORM config part ? this answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813300/symfony-error-the-class-xxx-was-not-found-in-the-chain-configured-namespaces-xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$cat` variable is the instance of `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Cursor`. but it should be instance of document.
So the code should change to:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository;

class ItemRepository extends DocumentRepository
{
    public function findAllQueryBuilder($filter = '')
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('item');

        if ($filter) {
            $cats = $this->getDocumentManager()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')
                ->findAllQueryBuilder($filter)->getQuery()->execute();

            foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                $qb->field('category')->includesReferenceTo($cat);
            }
        }

        return $qb;
    }
}
```